# TinyMCE 5 - sometimes textarea works perfectly but sometimes the toolbar and text entry don't appear

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE 5 in a PHP/MySQL web application.  Sometimes the textarea displays perfectly but sometimes it just appears as follows.  Refreshing the page will usually solve it and make the textarea appear ok.

Lack of reputation won't allow me to post images but link here >> https://i.ibb.co/8xgF0fS/screenshot.jpg

and when it works properly >> https://i.ibb.co/nfBdZnF/Capture.jpg

Seemingly no rhyme nor reason to why it appears or doesn't.

I am not using Turbolinks so have ruled out that cause. Tried moving the script to different places on the page and removing all css from the textarea.

The TinyMCE js is linked from the head of the page, direct from cloud.tinymce.com

Now left with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#mytextarea",
    browser_spellcheck: true,
    contextmenu: false,
    plugins: [
        "autosave","autoresize",
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table paste"
    ],
    autosave_interval: "10s",
    autoresize_bottom_margin: 25,
    max_height: 500,
    toolbar: "restoredraft | forecolor backcolor | insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
</script>
```

```
<textarea name="body" id="mytextarea" required=""></textarea>
```

Comment: Is there any error in the console of the devtools? There should be something.

Comment: Nothing, which is what perplexes me.  I sit with a user who sees the issue, no errors in the console.  I load the same page and it works perfectly, still no errors in the console.  I think it must be something to do with load time, that the tinymce.init is missed in some cases because the page takes longer to load.  Maybe if I host the tinymce locally rather than using the CDN link?  Or is my script tag in the wrong place?

Comment: Take a look here https://forums.meteor.com/t/tinymce-issues/23327

Comment: Thanks Saniya but that's a slightly different circumstance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no error in the console, then the only reason something like this might be happening is if your `tinymce` initialization script precedes declaration of the `textarea`. All such scripts should be invoked only when DOM is fully ready. Make sure you move the script all the way to the bottom of the page, just before closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Thanks jayarjo, I am coming to the same conclusion so have reworked the ordering of code on the page.  So far so good.  Appreciate your help.